# Hide specific instaces for IAM users in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, identity-management

I have multiple instances in my AWS account. I would like to list specific instances to the IAM users from the console.
Example: I have Instance1 and Instance 2. I would like to display Instance1 and hide Instance2 for IAM users.

I have attached the below policy. but still, all the instances are listed for IAM users in the AWS EC2 console.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DeleteTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

If you take a look at [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), the `DescribeInstances` API call only has a **Condition Key** to limit by Region. It is not possible to limit the result of this API call by any other critera (eg Tags).

So, users either have permission to list *ALL* of the instances, or None of them.

You can, of course, use **filters** in the management console to limit the instances displayed, but users would still be able to remove the filter or use the AWS CLI to list all instances.